# Sum of averages in pivot table

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have a data set that consists of multiple excel workbooks. Each workbook is a form where one individual in my firm rates the responses of 5 potential providers on a set of criteria. Each criteria has 2 "levels", and the score is given on the 2nd level. Data is structured as...

| Evaluator | Firm | Level 1 | Level 2 | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Robert | x | Support | Timezone | 30 |
| Robert | x | Support | Responsetime | 20 |
| Robert | x | Value | Strategic | 15 |
| Robert | x | Value | Technical | 20 |
| Robert | y | Support | Timezone | 25 |
| Robert | y | ... | ... | ... |

... and then the forms merged into a single table with powerquery, so there is one more column with the heading "evaluator", listing the name of the person who has provided that evaluation.

I want to create a pivot table that summerizes the data.

Level 1 of pivot table rows is "Level 1". Level 2 of pivot table rows is "Level 2". "Firm" is pivot table columns. In the values, I want a measure that calculates the average among all nonfiltered evaluators (got a slicer) if it is a level 2 item. If it is a level 1 item (that is, it is a subtotal for that group level 1), I want it to sum the averages of level 2 items.

Example: For a given firm, Robert has evaluated timezone to 30 and responsetime to 20. Paul has evaluated timezone to 20 and responsetime to 10. Assume these to are the only people selected in the "providers" slicer.

- Support - timezone: 25
- Support - responsetime: 15
- Support subtotal: 40 (not 20)

I am TOTALLY new to DAX, but believe this is where the answer lies, if at all possible. The googling I have done has not managed to make me cross the finish line. One and a half dax formulas for the time being:

1. Check whether it is a total row or a data row (probably better ways). Name ChkSubTotal

   `=NOT(ISFILTERED(table[lvl2]))`

This correctly shows by true or false if the cell is a subtotal or a proper value.

2. The formula I need help with:

`=if ([ChkSubTotal]; ??? ; CALCULATE(AVERAGE(table[Score])))`

What do I put in place of the ??? to get what I want? I will in some way have to make it calculate the averages for each level 2 of the given level 1, and then sum those averages.

I know summing averages isnt the smartest, but in this situations it is the scoring mechanism to be used. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think you're missing a column from your table. You should have Evaluator in there, because you'll have a set of records for each evaluator (Paul & Robert). it matters because you have to remove that Evaluator column from the evaluation context in some cases.